# MVC URL routing, routes to wrong route, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, url-routing

Question:

This is my RegisterRoutes:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


            routes.Add("ImagesRoute", new Route("graphics/{*filename}", new HttpRuntime.Routing.ImageRouteHandler()));


            // insert_dateti
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Routenname
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL mit Parametern
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameterstandardwerte
                //new { controller = "Home", action = "Splash", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameterstandardwerte
                //new { controller = "Folders", action = "Content", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameterstandardwerte
            );



        } // End Sub RegisterRoutes
```

And this is my route handler

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Linq; 
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.Compilation; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 


namespace HttpRuntime.Routing
{ 


    public class ImageRouteHandler : IRouteHandler 
    {


        public string MapRemoteLocation(string strPath)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strPath))
                return "";

            string strBaseURL = "http://madskristensen.net/themes/standard/";
            return strBaseURL + strPath;
        }

        public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext) 
        { 


            string filename = requestContext.RouteData.Values["filename"] as string; 

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename)) 
            {
                // return a 404 HttpHandler here
                requestContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 404;
                requestContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
                return null;
            } // End if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename)) 
            else 
            { 
                requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
                requestContext.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = GetContentType(filename);
                requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(MapRemoteLocation(filename));


                // find physical path to image here.   
                //string filepath = requestContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/test.jpg");


                // string stPath = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
                //requestContext.HttpContext.Response.WriteFile(filepath); 
                //requestContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
            } // End Else of if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename)) 

            return null; 
        } // End Function GetHttpHandler


        public static void MsgBox(object obj)
        {
            if (obj != null)
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(obj.ToString());
            else
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("obj is NULL");
        } // End Sub MsgBox


        private static string GetContentType(String path) 
        { 
            switch (Path.GetExtension(path)) 
            { 
                case ".bmp": return "Image/bmp"; 
                case ".gif": return "Image/gif"; 
                case ".jpg": return "Image/jpeg"; 
                case ".png": return "Image/png"; 
                default: break;
            } // End switch (Path.GetExtension(path))  
            return "";
        } // End Function GetContentType


    } // End Class ImageRouteHandler : IRouteHandler 


}  // End Namespace HttpRuntime.Routing
```

The goal of this is, that when i have this in /Home/Index.cshtml

```
<img src="graphics/mads2011.png?v=123" title="Compose E-Mail" alt="Compose E-Mail" />
```

it downloads the picture from a remote host.

It works fine as long as I have

```
routes.Add("ImagesRoute", new Route("graphics/{filename}", new HttpRuntime.Routing.ImageRouteHandler()));
```

But when I change it to

```
routes.Add("ImagesRoute", new Route("graphics/{*filename}", new HttpRuntime.Routing.ImageRouteHandler()));
```

in order to allow subfolders, then it redirects every url action to /graphics.

e.g. when I have

```
$(function () {
        $("#divJsTreeDemo").jstree({ 
        "json_data" : {
            "ajax" : {
                 "url": "@Url.Action("GetNodesJson", "Home")"
                 //"url": "@Url.Action("GetTreeData", "Home")"
                ,"async" : true
```

in Home/Index.cshtml

the URL for the AJAX call on the resulting HTML page becomes

```
"url": "/graphics?action=GetNodesJson&amp;controller=Home"
```

Why is this ?
And how can I fix this ?
If I move my ImagesRoute to the bottom, the JavaScript routes correctly, but then I can get no more remote images, because they are routed to controller "graphics", which doesn't exists --> Exception no such view...

Comment: I absolutely love aspnetmvc... I absolutely hate routing. I feel your pain. Sorry I cant help.

Comment: Oh, 1 piece of possible help is that I use a route debugger from http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/ when having routing issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When building links from routes, your `ImagesRoute` using `{*filename}` will satisfy all conditions, so that route will always be used to build links if it precedes your `Default` route in your routes table.  However, when processing requests, it works as expected, because the ImagesRoute route will only be satisfied by requests starting `http://mysite.com/graphics/...`

In order to fix this, you need to move the ImagesRoutes below the default route, and you then need to add a `RouteConstraint` to the Default route, so that any request starting with `graphics` will fail the Default route.

Change your Default route as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Routenname
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL mit Parametern
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // defaults
    new { controller = @"^(?!graphics).+" } // constraint
);
```

Comment: Great, works ! Thank you very much ! Though I must say I still don't understand why @Url.Action("GetNodesJson", "Home")" which is /Home/GetNodesJson satisfies /graphics/whatever. Or moreover why @Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName") turns into graphics/controllername/ActionName. Somehow, I guess, it just fills in the expanded route2 into route1... I suppose I have to read the sources of MVC to ever understand that routing part.

Comment: Because your ImagesRoute URL parameters consists of a single greedy match, it matches any link to be built by MVC.  On the link building side, everything matches that route.  Please mark as answered.  Thanks.